# How do I override only specific methods

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I'm currently working on a java me application and I have this code:

```
svgForm.setSVGEventListener(new SVGEventListener(){
                public void keyPressed(int i) {
                    System.out.println("Val"+i);
                }
                public void keyReleased(int i) {
                    System.out.println("Val"+i);
                }
                public void pointerPressed(int i, int i1) {
                    return;
                }
                public void pointerReleased(int i, int i1) {
                    return;
                }
                public void hideNotify() {
                    return;
                }
                public void showNotify() {
                    return;
                }
                public void sizeChanged(int i, int i1) {
                    return;
                }
});
```

However, like you see, I don't need to override all of the methods. Even worse, by overriding them I lose functionality. Is there a way keep the original methods and only override certain ones?

Comment: When implementing an interface, you have to override all methods declared by that interface.  The interface has no functionality, so how are you losing functionality?  If you are extending from a class that has implemented those methods, you can just omit them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have no choice, you need to implement them all.  However, a common pattern is to have a base class that provides no-op implementations of the methods in the interface, and then to extend that base class when you need to do something useful:

```
public class BaseSVGEventListener implements BaseSVGEventListener {
            public void keyPressed(int i) {}
            public void keyReleased(int i) {}
            public void pointerPressed(int i, int i1) {}
            public void pointerReleased(int i, int i1) {}
            public void hideNotify() {}
            public void showNotify() {}
            public void sizeChanged(int i, int i1) {}
}
```

And then:

```
svgForm.setSVGEventListener(new BaseSVGEventListener (){
            public void keyPressed(int i) {
                System.out.println("Val"+i);
            }
            public void keyReleased(int i) {
                System.out.println("Val"+i);
            }
});
```

There are many examples of this in the Java AWT/Swing APIs, for example [`FocusListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) and [`FocusAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusAdapter.html):

> An abstract adapter class for receiving keyboard focus events. The methods in this class are empty. This class exists as convenience for creating listener objects.
>
> Extend this class to create a `FocusEvent` listener and override the methods for the events of interest. (If you implement the `FocusListener` interface, you have to define all of the methods in it. This abstract class defines null methods for them all, so you can only have to define methods for events you care about.)

The Java API calls these "adapters", although that's a rather questionable use of that term. The "adapter pattern" is supposed to be used to adapt one type to another, which isn't what these API classes do.

Comment: You can find this pattern extensively in javax.swing. For example there´s the MouseListener interface, and the MouseAdapter implementation that saves you lots of typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're extending a class you can just omit any methods and allow them to be handled via the superclass. Alternatively you can just call `super();` in your implementation.

From a quick Google however, it appears to me that `SVGEventListener` is an interface NOT a class, so yes you will have to implement all methods. You should not be losing any functionality however since an `interface` has no implementation code - nothing to lose.

Answer (score 0):

1) do not use an anonymous class. Extend your own and you may only override what you need.

2) losing functionality is only because you do not use super.nameOfMethod() in the body of overridden methods.

3) learn very basics of Java. Might be worth spending a week or two reading a book on Java before your start working with it. And posting questions on trivial stuff.